# admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session)) in Flask-Admin and App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I have tried to deploy a flask app that uses Flask-Admin to Google App engine but once deployed it is returning the following error:

`AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'add_view'`

The following line is causing the error:
`admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))`

- Locally,the app works fine
- Locally, flasksqlalchemy connects to sqllite database but on App engine it's meant to connect to Cloud SQL

NOTE: PASSWORDS & DB DETAILS ARE MADE UP!

**main.py**

```
from flask_login import LoginManager,UserMixin,login_user,login_required,current_user,logout_user
from flask import Flask,request,render_template,redirect,url_for, Markup, send_file, session
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
import os
from config import config
from flask import Blueprint, render_template, redirect, url_for, request,flash
from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash, check_password_hash
from flask_admin import Admin 
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla import ModelView

app = Flask(__name__)
config_name='production'
app.config.from_object(config[config_name])
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'randomstring'
app.config['CSRF_ENABLED'] = True
app.config['USE_SESSION_FOR_NEXT'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
login_manager = LoginManager(app)
login_manager.login_view='login_get'
admin = Admin(app, template_mode='bootstrap3')

class User(UserMixin,db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(30),unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(30),unique=True)

if not os.path.isfile('dev_db.db'):
    db.create_all()
    admin = User(username='Admin', password='somepassword')
    person = User(username='Techteam', password='somepassword2')
    db.session.add(admin)
    db.session.add(person)
    db.session.commit()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.username)

admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))

@app.route('/')
def index(): 
    return render_template('index.html')
...
```

And this is my database configuration:

**config.py:**

```
USER='root'
PASSWORD='randompassword'
DATABASE='master'
CONNECTION_NAME='my-app-277020:us-central1:tool'

class Config:
        USER_APP_NAME='Tool'
        CSRF_ENABLED=True
        SECRET_KEY = '2365frtjislkmnqwers'

class Dev_Config(Config):
        ENV='development'
        DEBUG=True
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='sqlite:///dev_db.db'

class Prod_Config(Config):
        DEBUG=False
        ENV='production'
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = (
    'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@localhost/{database}'
    '?unix_socket=/cloudsql/{connection_name}').format(
        user=USER, password=PASSWORD,
        database=DATABASE, connection_name=CONNECTION_NAME)

config={'development': Dev_Config,
        'production': Prod_Config
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/gthread.py", line 92, in init_process
    super().init_process()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/opt/python3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/srv/main.py", line 39, in <module>
    admin.add_view(ModelView(User, db.session))
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'add_view'
```

Any ideas why this might be happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overriding value of `admin` from class `Admin` (`admin = Admin(...)`) to `User` (`admin = User(...)`) .

It is better not to use the same variable name for different purposes in your code.